# PHP Search Box not working?

Tags: php

I have created a search box that searches my website. I have tried really hard to fix it but it didn't work. Please could you help? The code is below:

```
  <?php
   $k = $_GET['k'];
   $terms = explode("  ", $k);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE " 

   for each ($terms as $each) {
       $i++;

       if ($i == 1) 
           $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
       else 
           $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
   }
   //connect
   mysql_connect("localhost", "my username", "my password");
   mysql_select_db("my database");

   $query = mysql_query($query);
   $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
   if ($numrows > 0){
       while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
           $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
           $description = $row['description'];
           $keywords = $row['keywords'];
           $link = $row['link'];

           echo "<h1><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>";
           $description<br  /><br />""
       }
   }
   else
       echo "No results found for \"<b>$k/b>\" ";
   //disconnect
   mysql_close();
  ?>
```

Comment: You can try to narrow down the problem by figuring out what is not working. The first step would be to insert a `var_dump($_GET)` at the beginning of your code to make sure that `$_GET['k']` exists..

Comment: start with changing `for each` to `foreach` to make it a valid loop

Comment: There are a few errors in that code. You should be seeing the errors printed on the screen, for instance "syntax error, unexpected 'for'" would be the first thing that should pop up which means you didn't escape the first part of the $query variable with ; The next error is for each should be foreach. Work with the errors as they appear

Comment: GCRDev How do i fix the for each. It is the only error i am receiving. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all, correct syntax. Instead of:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE " 
for each ($terms as $each) {
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";  
foreach ($terms as $each) {
```

and OUH, what's this???

```
$description<br  /><br />""
```

maybe youd learn the basics of syntax at first.